# .NET library which can switch socket from HTTP to WebSocket protocol

Tags: .net, http, websocket, server, port

I need to handle HTTP requests and WebSocket connections on single port 80 with my custom Windows service.

So, as I understand it: HTTP connection should be switched to WebSocket protocol on demand from client with Upgrade request header.

**Question**: Is there any server library that can handle HTTP requests on socket and can switch socket to WebSocket on demand?

Or may be there are any another solutions for standalone application/service?

Comment: SignalR ???????

Comment: it's IIS only. not a solution for me.

Comment: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

Comment: it has tons of dependencies. i am trying to resolve all conflicts on my VS2010. this is due to the fact that the required .NET version 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a TCP proxy port to divide traffic between the two targets. For example, all traffic would come in to port 80, but then HTTP traffic would be routed internally to 8001 and WS traffic to 8002.
https://github.com/lifeemotions/websocketproxy

Comment: with your solution an app should open 3 TCP ports and redirect traffic to himself. is it correct?

Comment: You set up websocketproxy on http port, run the http application on port 8081 and the websocket app on port 8082. Websocketproxy automatically sends the traffic to the desired location (http or ws)

Comment: I have to use all-in-one service and I trying to eliminate redundant elements.

Comment: A server can't have two different software applications listening on the same port/IP address. You could use two different IP addresses - and bind each application to their respective IP address.

Comment: I just want an app works with two protocols both on single port. I believe it is possible. But I can't find a proper library to reach this goal.